# Local DNS server + Firewall for reporting Setup

Tags: firewall, dns

My problem is the firewall is only recording DNS requests from my local DNS server instead of the source computer. I would like to keep using my local DNS server with External DNS servers being the backup but i also need the firewall to collect stats correctly.

It collects correctly when external DNS servers are used but i can't use local names then for shares and such.

Thoughts?

Windows DNS Server 2012

Sonicwall 240 (Firewall)

clients are all windows 7 machines.

Comment: Could you add some more information please?  For example, what kind of firewall is this, what type of DNS server, etc.  See the [NE Question Checklist](http://tinyurl.com/ne-checklist) for ways to help us help you.

Comment: Ok. Updated the original post.

Comment: What does the network look like? If the conversations between the clients and the internal DNS server do not pass the firewall, it can't record them. If that is the case, either collect the info on the DNS server or make the traffic pass the firewall.

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gerben is correct--DNS requests from your Windows 7 clients will not traverse the Sonicwall firewall to reach your Windows Server.  If you really wanted to do this, you would need to use one of the available ports on your firewall and create a DMZ network.  You will need to move (change the IP address and move the port) your Windows server to this new DMZ network.  You will need to setup the access lists between the internal network and the DMZ server network in the same way you setup the access lists to the internet.

Comment: Thanks. I think the solution is finding a different way of recording user Internet usage.